# Django - Return posts with avatar url of creator

Tags: python, django

I have this class called `User`, which has an `ImageField` attribute, which stores the user's avatar/profile picture. I'm trying to annotate a `Post` query set so that just the user's avatar url gets returned with the post none of the other data. I've tried 2 different ways to annotate the query, but get errors as you can see below when I ping the views to get posts. **How do I attach user avatar url with the return annotated `Post` query set?**

`models.py`

```
class User(AbstractDatesModel):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=USERNAME_MAX_LEN, unique=True, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(USERNAME_MIN_LEN)])
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatar_directory_path, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def avatar_url(self):
        return self.avatar.url

class Post(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=generate_ulid_as_uuid, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator")
    body = models.CharField(max_length=POST_MAX_LEN, validators=[MinLengthValidator(POST_MIN_LEN)])
```

`annotator.py`

```
def query_to_full_post_data_serializer(post_query_set: QuerySet):
    query_set_annotated = post_query_set.annotate(
        creator_username=F('creator__username'),
        creator_avatar_url=F('creator__avatar_url')
    )
    return FullPostDataSerializer(query_set_annotated, many=True)
```

`annotator_version_2.py`

```
def query_to_full_post_data_serializer(post_query_set: QuerySet):
    query_set_annotated = post_query_set.annotate(
        creator_username=F('creator__username'),
        creator_avatar_url=F('creator__avatar__url')
    )
    return FullPostDataSerializer(query_set_annotated, many=True)
```

`annotator.py` gives the error:
`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'avatar_url' into field. Choices are: avatar, cheer_post, cheer_reply, created, creator_username, followee_id, follower_id, friendship_creator, friendshiprequest, goal_creator, goal_follow, goal_join, post_creator, reply, updated_at, userinterests, username, uuid`

`annotator_version_2.py` gives the error:
`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'url' into field. Join on 'avatar' not permitted.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this instead.

```
def query_to_full_post_data_serializer(post_query_set: QuerySet):
    query_set_annotated = post_query_set.annotate(
        creator_username=F('creator__username'),
        creator_avatar_url=F('creator__avatar')
    )
    return FullPostDataSerializer(query_set_annotated, many=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think doing `creator__avatar` actually returns the full avatar info, which entails metadata related things and I think it errors out.

Comment: so I think it works? I'm not too sure. If I use `self.user.avatar.url` it equals `/media/images/user_6badb4b8-33ba-4bb9-aa9a-2e3afb359960/avatar_HK055t5.jpg`, but what is returned in the response for `creator_avatar_url` is `images/user_6badb4b8-33ba-4bb9-aa9a-2e3afb359960/avatar_HK055t5.jpg`